# Не отрисовывается прямоугольник в PyQt5 - QPainter

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qpainter, paintevent

Имеется программа для **`преобразования температуры из градусов цельсия в фаренгейт и обратно`**. В первое поле ввода пользователь должен ввести значение, нажать на нужную кнопку для преобразования и в форме ниже (с надписью ответ) должен появиться результат преобразования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также, после появления во второй форме результата, должен отрисовываться прямоугольник (шкала) в самой нижней нарисованной форме, длина которого была бы равна результату преобразования температуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что должно было бы получиться примерно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня не получается это сделать. Ниже будет расположен код, а сейчас я расскажу общий принцип работы отрисовки в этом коде: 
метод `paintEvent` в классе `FormBuilder` активируется постоянно (я скопировал данный код с другого сайта, и не очень понимаю принцип такой работы, но в общем смысл такой) и при первом запуске программы (`self.launch = "first"`) происходит запуск метода `draw_thermometer`, который рисует "корпус термометра" и меняет переменную `self.launch` равной `"second"`.

Теперь, при активации метода `paintEvent`, происходит выполнение метода `fill_thermometer`, но рисование "шкалы" термометра (как на фотографии выше, красная шкала) не происходит.

Прошу помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с данной проблемой. Буду безмерно рад любой помощи!

PS важные участки кода (которые отвечают за рисование) пометил комментарием `# важный метод!`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, \
    QGroupBox, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPen, QIcon

WINDOW_HEIGHT = 210
WINDOW_WIDTH = 300
WINDOW_NAME = 'Температура'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'Images\\main_logo.png'

MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.launch = "first"

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.heading_label = QLabel()
        self.entering_label = QLabel()

        self.first_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Значение T")
        self.second_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Ответ")

        self.celc_button = QPushButton("К Цельсия")
        self.far_button = QPushButton("К Фаренгейт")

        self.first_draw_label = QLabel(" ")
        self.second_draw_label = QLabel(" ")

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.heading_label.setText("Преобразование температуры C-F")
        self.heading_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE, QFont.Bold))

        self.entering_label.setText("Температурное значение")
        self.entering_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))

        self.second_value.setDisabled(True)

        self.celc_button.setMinimumWidth(125)
        self.celc_button.clicked.connect(self.make_celc)

        self.far_button.clicked.connect(self.make_far)

        self.first_draw_label.resize(500, 500)

    def create_layers(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        heading_label = QHBoxLayout()
        heading_label.addWidget(self.heading_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(heading_label)

        self.first_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.entering_label.text())
        self.first_groupbox.setStyleSheet('''
                    QGroupBox {
                        margin-top: 2ex;
                    }
                    QGroupBox:enabled {
                        border: 3px solid gray;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                    }
                    QGroupBox::title {
                        subcontrol-origin: margin;
                        left: 3ex;
                    }
                ''')
        first_groupbox_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.first_groupbox)
        first_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.first_value)
        first_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.second_value)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.first_groupbox)

        button_line = QFormLayout()
        button_line.addRow(self.celc_button, self.far_button)
        main_layout.addLayout(button_line)

        first_draw_label = QHBoxLayout()
        first_draw_label.addWidget(self.first_draw_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(first_draw_label)

        second_draw_label = QHBoxLayout()
        second_draw_label.addWidget(self.second_draw_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(second_draw_label)

    def paintEvent(self, e): # важный метод!
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.launch == "first":
            self.draw_thermometer(qp)
        elif self.launch == "second":
            self.fill_thermometer(qp)
        qp.end()

    def draw_thermometer(self, qp): # важный метод!
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(112, 106, 104))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(10, 150, 260, 35, 5, 5)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(194, 189, 186))
        qp.drawRect(15, 155, 250, 25)

        self.launch = 2

    def make_celc(self):
        try:
            if float(self.first_value.text())  212:
                self.first_value.setText("212")

            self.second_value.setText("Ответ")

            result = round((float(self.first_value.text()) - 32) * (5 / 9), 3)
            self.second_value.setText(str(result))

            self.launch = "second"
        except:
            self.second_value.setText("Неправильный ввод!")

    def make_far(self):
        try:
            if float(self.first_value.text())  100:
                self.first_value.setText("100")

            self.second_value.setText("Ответ")

            result = round((float(self.first_value.text()) * (9 / 5)) + 32, 3)
            self.second_value.setText(str(result))

            self.launch = "second"
        except:
            self.second_value.setText("Неправильный ввод!")

    def fill_thermometer(self, qp): # важный метод!
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(109, 160, 201))
        rect_lenght = round(float(self.second_value.text()))
        qp.drawRect(17, 157, rect_lenght, 21)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я попробовал, что-то для вас сделать, если не спите - попробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, \
    QGroupBox, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPainter, QColor, QPen, QIcon


WINDOW_HEIGHT = 210
WINDOW_WIDTH = 300
WINDOW_NAME = 'Температура'
WINDOW_ICON_NAME = 'im.png'                    # 'Images\\main_logo.png'

MAIN_FONT = 'Times'
FONT_HEADER_SIZE = 11                          # 13
FONT_BODY_SIZE = 8


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.launch = "first"                                    # ваша проблемнаяя переменная !

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.fill_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.heading_label = QLabel()
        self.entering_label = QLabel()

        self.first_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Значение T")
        self.second_value = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Ответ")  # ваша проблемнаяя переменная !      

        self.celc_button = QPushButton("К Цельсия")
        self.far_button = QPushButton("К Фаренгейт")

        self.first_draw_label = QLabel(" ")
        self.second_draw_label = QLabel(" ")

    def fill_forms(self):
        self.heading_label.setText("Преобразование температуры C-F")
        self.heading_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE, QFont.Bold))
        self.entering_label.setText("Температурное значение")
        self.entering_label.setFont(QFont(MAIN_FONT, FONT_HEADER_SIZE))
        self.second_value.setDisabled(True)
        self.celc_button.setMinimumWidth(125)
        self.celc_button.clicked.connect(self.make_celc)
        self.far_button.clicked.connect(self.make_far)
        self.first_draw_label.resize(500, 500)

    def create_layers(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        heading_label = QHBoxLayout()
        heading_label.addWidget(self.heading_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(heading_label)

        self.first_groupbox = QGroupBox(self.entering_label.text())
        self.first_groupbox.setStyleSheet('''
                    QGroupBox {
                        margin-top: 2ex;
                    }
                    QGroupBox:enabled {
                        border: 3px solid gray;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                    }
                    QGroupBox::title {
                        subcontrol-origin: margin;
                        left: 3ex;
                    }
                ''')
        first_groupbox_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.first_groupbox)
        first_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.first_value)
        first_groupbox_layout.addWidget(self.second_value)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.first_groupbox)

        button_line = QFormLayout()
        button_line.addRow(self.celc_button, self.far_button)
        main_layout.addLayout(button_line)

        first_draw_label = QHBoxLayout()
        first_draw_label.addWidget(self.first_draw_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(first_draw_label)

        second_draw_label = QHBoxLayout()
        second_draw_label.addWidget(self.second_draw_label)
        main_layout.addLayout(second_draw_label)

    def paintEvent(self, e):                                      # важный метод!
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        
        qp.setBrush(QColor(112, 106, 104))                               # +++
        qp.drawRoundedRect(10, 150, 260, 35, 5, 5)                       # +++        
        qp.setBrush(QColor(194, 189, 186))                               # +++
        qp.drawRect(15, 155, 250, 25)                                    # +++ 
        
        if self.first_value.text() and self.second_value.text():         # +++ !!! ВАЖНО
            if self.launch == "first":
                self.draw_thermometer(qp)
            elif self.launch == "second":
                self.fill_thermometer(qp)
        qp.end()

    def make_celc(self):
        try:
# ?                                            vv <----- что это ???        
# ?           if float(self.first_value.text())  212:
            if float(self.first_value.text()) == 212:
                self.first_value.setText("212")

# ?           self.second_value.setText("Ответ")         # placeholderText   ???

            result = round((float(self.first_value.text()) - 32) * (5 / 9), 3)
            self.second_value.setText(str(result))

# ?           self.launch = "second"                          # ???
            self.launch = "first"                                                  # +++
            
        except:
# ?           self.second_value.setText("Неправильный ввод!") # ???
            self.second_value.clear()                                              # +++
            self.second_value.setPlaceholderText("Неправильный ввод!")             # +++

        self.update()                                                              # +++ ВАЖНО !!!
        
    def make_far(self):
        try:
# ??                                            vv  <<------ что это ?        
# ??           if float(self.first_value.text())  100:
            if float(self.first_value.text()) == 100:
                self.first_value.setText("100")

#?            self.second_value.setText("Ответ")

            result = round((float(self.first_value.text()) * (9 / 5)) + 32, 3)
            self.second_value.setText(str(result))
            self.launch = "second"
        except:
#            self.second_value.setText("Неправильный ввод!")
            self.second_value.clear()                                                # +++
            self.second_value.setPlaceholderText("Неправильный ввод!")               # +++

        self.update()                                                              # +++ ВАЖНО !!!

    def draw_thermometer(self, qp):                            # важный метод!
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)                        
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        ''' # НЕТ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        print(f'    def draw_thermometer(self, qp): {qp}')  
        qp.setBrush(QColor(112, 106, 104))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(10, 150, 260, 35, 5, 5)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(194, 189, 186))
        qp.drawRect(15, 155, 250, 25)
        ''' # НЕТ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        qp.setBrush(QColor(10, 216, 20))
        rect_lenght = round(float(self.second_value.text()))
        qp.drawRect(17, 157, rect_lenght, 21)
        
# ??        self.launch = 2     <<------ что это ? 
        
    def fill_thermometer(self, qp):                             # важный метод!
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)

#        qp.setBrush(QColor(109, 160, 201))
        qp.setBrush(QColor(10, 16, 201))
        rect_lenght = round(float(self.second_value.text()))
        qp.drawRect(17, 157, rect_lenght, 21)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_NAME)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(WINDOW_ICON_NAME))

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.main_grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        form_builder_object = FormBuilder()
        self.main_grid.addWidget(form_builder_object, 0, 0, Qt.AlignTop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо Вам большое! Я говорю Вам спасибо каждый раз, когда Вы мне помогаете и возможно Вы можете подумать, что это не искренно, но это искренне, просто Вы на каждый мой вопрос даете ответ :D. И вот у меня еще возник вопрос по методу из Вашего добавленного кода, можете, пожалуйста, подсказать? Почему мы должны использовать метод "update"? (в интернете искал, но не нашёл. Залазил в docs, но там не нашёл даже сам список методов)

Comment: @GunTHE вы рано ложитесь спать и поздно встаете :). Читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update

Comment: вооот, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @GunTHE  пожалуйста